# Cannot access class before initialization

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm creating a circular dependency between two classes which uses the same decorator for renaming some properties I get from a backend-service (backend-service properties are named in german and I want to rename them in a generic way):

```
// request.ts

export class Request {
    id: string;
    @JsonProperty('dienst')
    service: Service;
}
```

```
// service.ts

export class Service {
    id: string;
    @JsonProperty('letzteAntraege')
    lastRequests: Request[];
    @JsonProperty('beschreibung')
    description: string;
}
```

I'm using `reflect-metadata` to get the property-type within the decorator:

```
export function JsonProperty(serviceName: string) {
    return (target: Object, key: string) => {
        const keyType = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, key);
   }
}
```

which leads to following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Service' before initialization
    at Module.Service (request.ts:17:22)
    at Module.5115 (request.ts:17:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.6218 (request.ts:17:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.2226 (request.service.ts:10:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.9859 (services.component.html:10:71)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.3176 (main.js:15:97)
```

Any ideas how to avoid this?

Edit: So the problem (I guess) is that the decorators code is executed on initializing `Request`, which in this case is too early. It should only be executed after all types are initialized.

Comment: Have you tried initializing `Service`?

Comment: How could I do that? If I'd try to init `Service` first, I'd have the problem that `Request` is not initialized yet, I guess.

Comment: Which is why I linked xyproblem.info.  Tell us what the *actual* problem is, and maybe we can suggest a way to fix it (hint: it's not your error message).